# How to declare JavaScript class "google.visualization.AreaChart" in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to declare JavaScript code for class defined by point notation:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
```

I have tried different approaches but nothing works correctly. For example:

```
external class Google {
    val visualization: Visualization
    class Visualization {
        class AreaChart(element: Element?) {
            fun draw(chartDataTable: dynamic, options: dynamic)
        }
    }
}

external val google: Google

val chart = Google.Visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'))
```

is by Kotlin never translated correctly.

I need

```
var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
```

but I get invalid:

```
  var Google$Visualization$AreaChart = Google.Visualization.AreaChart;
  var chart = new Google$Visualization$AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kotlin annotation [`JsQualifier`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/-js-qualifier/index.html) can be used to do this.

Put `AreaChart` into its own file and mark the file with `@file:JsQualifier("google.visualization")`:

```
@file:JsQualifier("google.visualization")

import org.w3c.dom.Element

external class AreaChart(element: Element?) {
    fun draw(chartDataTable: dynamic, options: dynamic)
}
```

Then create a new object of the class `AreaChart` as usual:

```
val chart = AreaChart(document.getElementById("chart_div"));
```

Kotlin compiles this to:

```
var AreaChart = google.visualization.AreaChart;
var chart;
Object.defineProperty(_, 'chart', {
    get: function () {
        return chart;
    }
});
chart = new AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
```

Unfortunately there is an [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-23561) in the Kotlin JS compiler which prevents the Google Charts lacy loading from working together with the code created by Kotlin.

A workaround for that is described at https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/problem-with-declarations-added-by-kotlin-js/7177/4

Comment: Thank you Alexander for answer. I have one more trouble with this. If I use this declaration in my class file and this class file is within package I am not able to import this class AreaChart because it is not within package. 
And my project can't be build. I am forced to use only files without package. Am I missing something?

Comment: Or maybe i should ask another question from the beginning. It would be possible for Kotlin team to create an sample how to implement [this use case](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart#a-simple-example) in Kotlin? There is many questions within and I could not find enough information to solve this.

Comment: Packages work fine for me. I added `package google.visualization` as the second line after `@file:JsQualifier("google.visualization")` in the file which contains `AreaChart`. In my case `AreaChar.kt`. The in the file (in my case `main.kt`) which contains `val chart = ...` I added `import google.visualization.AreaChart`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Packages are working. But still I think not correct code is produced because when page is loading exception is thrown `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'AreaChart' of undefined`. And I did not yet called method `main()` . JS for google charts is ofc defined in html header.

Comment: I just checked this again and found https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-23561 which prevents this from working. You may use https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/problem-with-declarations-added-by-kotlin-js/7177/4 as a workaround.

Comment: Thank You Alexander, ok, I will stuck with plain JS for now.